# Error writing to plist in documents directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, plist, documentsdirectory

I use the following code to copy a Resources plist file into the documents directory:

```
BOOL success;
NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test-Info.plist"];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

if (!success) {
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"Test-Info.plist"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:filePath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Test-Info.plist successfully copied to DocumentsDirectory.");
}
```

I get the success message, which is great. I'm assuming it's been copied correctly into the documents folder.

However when I then try to read and write to the saved plist file it returns null:

Key entry in Test-Info.plist:

```
Key: EnableEverything
Type: Boolean
Value: YES
```

Write code:

```
NSString *adKey = @"EnableEverything";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test-Info.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSString *enableEverything = [[plist valueForKey:adKey] stringValue];
NSLog(@"****** EXISTING: %@ ******", enableEverything); // returns (null)

// Disable in plist.
[plist setValue:0 forKey:adKey]; // will this work?
[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; // this doesn't throw an error?

NSString *enableEverything1 = [[plist valueForKey:adKey] stringValue];
NSLog(@"****** NOW: %@ ******", enableEverything1); // returns (null)
```

Output:

```
****** EXISTING: (null) ******
****** NOW: (null) ******
```

My question is why are they `(null)` when they exist within the plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mutate an immutable object.

You need a [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/).

IE

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path] mutableCopy];
```

Also check, if the plist object isnt nil, as any messages can be send to nil without raiing an error. this wouldnt fail, also nothing actually happens.

```
[plist setValue:0 forKey:adKey]; // will this work?
[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; // this doesn't throw an error?
```

---

as the source path is nil, you are most like not copying the file during <strike>compilation</strike> bundling. drag it here:

[image]

Comment: BTW: why the hassle with a file? it seems to be a perfect usecase of NSUserDefaults

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks a million.

Comment: :) one hour. Damn, I should have work that hour and charge a client for it…

Comment: In my case I had to remove the plist from my documents directory so that it would write my new values after I built.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for nsbundle path for resource

```
NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SportsLogo-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Try allocating

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

Also check if the file has been copied or not. Go to Library=>Application Support=>iPhone Simulator=>folder named your version of simulator iOS=>Applications=>Find the right folder of your project=>Documents see if the plist file is there

Comment: What is wrong with `NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];`? (except that it needs to be mutable)

Comment: I agree, however it's still returning nil.

Comment: Actually, I'm not checking the DocumentsDirectory. Neo's right, it doesn't exist so it hasn't been copied. The question is, why isn't it copying to the DocumentsDirectory successfully?

Comment: you mean SportsLogo-Info.plist doesnt exits or the source path isnt right?

Comment: probably it isnt copied to the bundle. see my answer how to do so.